# Flash file does not display in webview 

Tags: android, flash, android-webview

I try to load a .swf file from assets folder to a webview, but I am not able to display it.

Here is the code:

```java
package com.androidpeople.view;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewExample extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    String html =
        "<object width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> <param name=\"movie\"   value=\"file:///android_asset/co.swf\"> <embed src=\"file:///android_asset/co.swf\" width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> </embed> </object>";
        String mimeType = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";
        ;
    WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
    wv.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());



}
}
package com.androidpeople.view;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

}
```

Manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.androidpeople.view"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".WebViewExample"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Now I got a new error:

```
06-30 06:17:35.207: ERROR/MetadataRetrieverClient(33): failed to extract an album art
```

Comment: i update code plz see it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please used below code

```
String html =
"<object width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> <param name=\"movie\" value=\"file:///android_asset/co.swf\"> <embed src=\"file:///android_asset/co.swf\" width=\"550\" height=\"400\"> </embed> </object>";
String mimeType = "text/html";
String encoding = "utf-8";
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

---

### **OR**

Reefer [this link](http://androidforums.com/application-development/171895-play-local-swf-file-flash-webview.html)

Comment: thanks for give a good code , but my problem is Android runtime logcate.now error are remove,but when i run project it not run.

Comment: Means what things is not run?

Comment: in which android phone test it? and which version?

Comment: please try emulator in 2.3 if you find this answer is helpful then upvote and right this answer then may be helpful to other.

Comment: i got this kind of error when i am run project in avd 2.3.1
06-30 06:17:35.207: ERROR/MetadataRetrieverClient(33): failed to extract an album art

Comment: do you think that to load swf file we have install flash first in emulator?